# Two circles externally tangent find distance from the center of smaller circle to the point of tangency.

Tags: geometry

The radius of two circles that are tangent externally to each other is $r$ and $s$.Suppose $r>s$ and two outer tangent of circles intersect at point $P$.Denote the center of smaller circle by $O$.Find $|OP|$

My problem:From figure I think $|OP|=r$,is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

From the similarity of triangles 
$$ \frac{x}{x+(r+s)} = \frac{s}{r} $$
where $x=|OP|$.
Thus
$$ x=s\frac{r+s}{r-s} $$